# I can't edit local.xml using Docker

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml

I deploy on server my magento site with docker + plesk 
all is correct but i cant edit or change permission on path /etc

I can't edit local.xml with my correct db data.

Comment: What docker image are you using? Something from github.com? You probably need to create some folder mounts with files that reside outside of docker instance in host OS which docker instance then reads

Comment: Hello Dominic, I use an image create to another company.

I fix change permission from ssh